# How to insert <br /> tags into a FacesMessage?

Tags: jsf

i've this code for validate notification

```
public Boolean validate(){
        Boolean errorFlag = false;
        String errMsg = "";
        
        try {   
        
            if(shift.getDescription() == null || shift.getDescription().isEmpty()){
                errorFlag = true;
                errMsg = errMsg + "<br>" + "description harus diisi";
                
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorFlag = true;
            errMsg = "";
        }
```

but, the "br" didnt break my notification line like this :
[image: notification]

any clue?

Comment: In Java, you can use `\n` to represent a line break.

Comment: i've tried this and still not working :|

Answer (score -1):

errMsg = errMsg + "\ndescription harus diisi";

Should give you the result you're looking for.
\n is an escape character that represents as a break line in a Java String.

Comment: Not very likely, unless it is output inside `<pre>. . .</pre>` in the JSF. `\n` is a newline.

Comment: i've tried this and still not working :|

Answer (score -2):

I think this is a frontend question.The style of display should be decided by frontend.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe instead of

```
errMsg = errMsg + "<br>" + "description harus diisi";
```

Write

```
errMsg = errMsg + System.lineSeparator() + "description harus diisi";
```